# Cannot install NPM package "java" alongside Electron

Tags: java, npm, electron, npm-install

I'm trying to install the NPM `java` package alongside Electron, Angular and Python and I've also installed `node-gyp`, but the installation process fails with the following error messages:

```
 C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\electronapp\node_modules\java>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
    [node-java] Error: not found: javac.exe
    gyp: Call to 'node findJavaHome.js' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
    gyp ERR! configure error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\electronapp\node_modules\java
    gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! java@0.10.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.10.0 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-26T10_16_59_435Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You'll need the JDK (Java Development Kit) to use that NPM package, [as its documentation states](https://www.npmjs.com/package/java). That Windows can't find `javac.exe` means that you haven't installed the JDK or didn't add its path to the `%PATH%` global variable. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/install/overview-jdk-installation.html) for JDK 11 installation instructions.

Comment: i have installed jdk thats perfect fine. i have checked with javac command also. but still getting same error .

Answer (score 2):

Before installing Java, we need to install Windows build tools using the following command:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

The above command will install supportive build tools for Visual Studio Code and Python.